# How to write url for request with params in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make a get request for this type of url:

http://localhost:9000/data?start-time=1234124

I want to define route in ExpressJS:

```
app.get("/data",function(req,res){
})
```

How to set parameter start-time in url?

Thanks :)

Comment: your question is not clear. How to `set` or How to `get` start-time ?

Answer (score 0):

Query string parameters are contained in the `req.query` object. If you want to get start-time, try this:

```
app.get("/data", function(req, res) {
  let startTime = req.query['start-time'];
});
```